# Control graph(call graph) for entire java project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Im currently working on a java project, can i get any tool(or plugin in eclipse) that can gives me entire flow graph(call graph) of the project (apart from doxygen ,which i tried already), so that it can helps me to understand it quickly..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Isn't Call Hierarchy what you're searching for (Ctrl+Alt+H)?

Comment: But it will give for current function only.. There is some way to get entire flow..

Answer (score 1):

See [CallGraph Viewer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/callgraph-viewer#.Ua2WC9IepyQ) on the marketplace.

Also standard shortcut `Ctrl-Alt-H` may help.

Comment: But it will give for current function only.. There is some way to get entire flow..